# Smooth natural motion when page scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am newbie in JS. Right now i am working on an effect in which i want when page scroll first time then the natural motion animation starts but it's creating a problem because when i scroll the element animation became fast.

Check this more you got the idea.

http://jsfiddle.net/byvLy/

Comment: what kind of motion are you building?

Comment: I'm not sure what are you trying to do? How about this: http://jsfiddle.net/byvLy/2/

Comment: @Joseph I like this type of motion on page scroll http://jsfiddle.net/byvLy/5/

Comment: @codef0rmer it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i know that this is a swinging box (figured it out due to the `Math.sin()`)

however, you have to note that scrolling event is fired every few milliseconds during scrolling. in your code, you are calling animate and creating an interval every time the scroll event is fired. that's why your animation is jumpy;

[try this instead](http://jsfiddle.net/byvLy/6/):

```
$(function() {

    $(window).on('scroll', function() {
        swing.start('.cloud1, .cloud2');
    });

    var swing = (function() {
        var animated = false;

        function startAnimation(selector) {
            if (!animated) {
                var banner = $(selector);
                var start = 0;

                animated = true;
                window.setInterval(function() {
                    banner.css('left', 100 * Math.sin(start) + 80);
                    start += 0.1;
                }, 30);
            }
        }
        return {
            start: startAnimation
        }
    }());
});​
```

Comment: I changed the interval and the start variable increments to make the swing more visible. just change them back.

Comment: can i add more elements on this or i have to write this for all element one by one

Comment: updated my answer to accomodate more elements using jQuery selectors